# Sending Bitcoin from LocalBitcoin to another wallet to secure my funds, does it work?

Tags: privacy, account-to-account

I have an account with LocalBitcoin, that I use to ONLY fund my backpage account. However, this account is on the clearnet, is linked to my email address and bank account, and has been used without any privacy/protection layer whatsoever. I live in a place that do not seems to have any option for cash payment to get bitcoins, that's why I used my bank account to fund it and didn't consider protecting it when I first used it.

Well, now I would like to purchase something with bitcoins, but I do not want this transaction to be linked in any way to my LocalBitcoin account (and all personal information).

My questions are:

- If I cannot fund an account by cash payment, can I create another account from a different website, to which I would be safely sending bitcoins from my LocalBitcoin account?
- Does this allow me a certain layer of security/privacy considering that this new account would be created with a different identity, and dedicated only to usage with TOR browser?
- Does Bitcoin transfer the bitcoins from normal web to TOR Network securely in any way?

Thanks a lot

(I'm really sorry if I do not use the right terms, im not a pro in these languages)

Comment: I've slightly edited your post for grammar and formatting. There seemed to be a word missing in the second question because it ended in "and ?", so you might want to edit your question to add the remainder of your thought there.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! You can help the site by marking answers as accepted if they are correct and address the question so that the question does not remain as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1):

> Does Bitcoin transfer from normal web to TOR Network secure in any way the bitcoin?

Transactions in Bitcoin are linkable. In other words, if you anonymously sent me Bitcoins to address 123, I could see that those bitcoins used to belong to address 456. If I also had a copy of LocalBitcoin's database, I could see that address 456 belongs to you. I would have a high degree of confidence that the Bitcoins came from you.

Tor doesn't fix that, but it's still a good idea. Tor can hide your IP address, but in the above example, I never used that anyway.

Comment: Okay, so thats means that (e.g.) Localbitcoin adress 123 sending to Anonymous address 456, who send again to buy to adress 789.

Comment: thats means (e.g.) origin address 123 sending to Anon. address 456, who send to buy from adress 789.Tracing can be done all the up the chain....But  Wouldnt it be really simply a guess to say that address 456 is own by the same person as address 123 ?? Adding other Anonymous" address afterward should increase the chance to reduce "certainty" of such guess....If done prior the final purchase to last person..... If I would send bitcoin to unknown party, and this person would then send bitcoin to another unknown person...and over again....isnt that the same thing ?

Comment: @Chaniny That could work. That's called 'Bitcoin mixing,' but I don't know how well it works. You're fighting an uphill battle, because you need the mixing done now, but the data that potentially links those transactions will exist forever.